# HTML Text not centering

Tags: html, alignment

I have been having a problem with my code, I wanted the text to be in the centre, but no matter what I do, it just won't go there. I have added a comment indicating the location of the text I wanted to be centred. Any help is appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Mix Pics</title>
 <meta name="description" content="A photography-inspired website layout with an expanding stack slider and a background image tilt effect" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="photography, template, layout, effect, expand, image stack, animation, flickity, tilt" />
 <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flickity.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
 <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="hero">
   <div class="hero__back hero__back--static"></div>
   <div class="hero__back hero__back--mover"></div>
   <div class="hero__front"></div>
  </div>
  <header class="codrops-header">
   <div class="codrops-links">
    <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon--prev" href="index.html" title="Home Page"><span>Home Page</span></a>
    <a class="codrops-icon codrops-icon--drop" href="index.html" title="Home Page"><span>Home Page</span></a>
   </div>
   <h1 class="codrops-title">Mix <span>Pics</span></h1>
   <div align="center">
   <h3>About</h3> <!-- This text for some reason is in the top right hand corner, not the centre. -->
   </div>
   </body>
```

Comment: When I run the code snippet, it is aligned in the centre perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but when I run it from the localhost, it is in the top right hand corner.

Comment: Is this your total code? As far as I can see you have opened a <header> tag but never closed it. Maybe you should take a closer look at your code to see if there are any errors.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fbj65n -- Closing the <header> tag never fixed it either

Comment: When you inspect the text using your browser dev tools (`F12`), it should show you the actual size of the box and the associated CSS rules (including where they can be found and the rules they supersede). You should check that, and come back to us with the info you got there or a screenshot if you still have no idea what the problem is.